# Could not resolve peer peer dependency for any installation

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, npm-install

I am trying to run my app in dev client expo but everytime I get errors.

I have deleted node_modules folder and equally my package-lock.json but when I then run `npm install` I get this error:

```
 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: project@1.0.0
    npm ERR! Found: @react-navigation/native@6.1.3
    npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/native
    npm ERR!   @react-navigation/native@"^6.0.7" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! peer @react-navigation/native@"^5.0.5" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.9
    npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
    npm ERR!   @react-navigation/stack@"^5.14.9" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! See C:\Users\alexander\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\alexander\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-05T23_08_29_526Z-debug-0.log

When I hadn't deleted `package-lock.json`, I would get this error:

npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: project@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: @react-native-firebase/app@14.12.0
npm WARN node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm WARN   @react-native-firebase/app@"^15.1.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @react-native-firebase/app@"14.11.1" from @react-native-firebase/firestore@14.11.1
npm WARN node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore
npm WARN   @react-native-firebase/firestore@"^14.3.0" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: project@1.0.0
npm WARN Found: @react-native-firebase/app@14.12.0
npm WARN node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm WARN   @react-native-firebase/app@"^15.1.1" from the root project
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @react-native-firebase/app@"15.6.0" from @react-native-firebase/messaging@15.6.0
npm WARN node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging
npm WARN   @react-native-firebase/messaging@"^15.1.1" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.3
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   128 more (@eliav2/react-native-collapsible-view, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.3
npm WARN node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
npm WARN   @callstack/react-theme-provider@"3.0.3" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.3
npm WARN   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
npm WARN     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"3.0.3" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   128 more (@eliav2/react-native-collapsible-view, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"16.x.x" from modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/modal-react-native-web
npm WARN   modal-react-native-web@"0.2.0" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm WARN 
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"16.x.x" from modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/modal-react-native-web
npm WARN     modal-react-native-web@"0.2.0" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN Found: react-dom@17.0.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm WARN   10 more (@react-aria/combobox, @react-aria/menu, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"16.x.x" from modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/modal-react-native-web
npm WARN   modal-react-native-web@"0.2.0" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"16.x.x" from modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/modal-react-native-web
npm WARN     modal-react-native-web@"0.2.0" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN Found: react-native-web@0.17.1
npm WARN node_modules/react-native-web
npm WARN   react-native-web@"0.17.1" from the root project
npm WARN   2 more (react-native-country-picker-modal, react-native-maps)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-native-web@"0.9.x" from modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/modal-react-native-web
npm WARN   modal-react-native-web@"0.2.0" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-web@0.9.13
npm WARN node_modules/react-native-web
npm WARN   peer react-native-web@"0.9.x" from modal-react-native-web@0.2.0
npm WARN   node_modules/modal-react-native-web
npm WARN     modal-react-native-web@"0.2.0" from react-native-country-picker-modal@2.0.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native-country-picker-modal
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: native-base@3.3.7
npm ERR! Found: react-native-safe-area-context@3.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!   react-native-safe-area-context@"3.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@">= 3.0.0" from @react-navigation/drawer@6.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/drawer@"^6.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (@react-navigation/elements, react-native-elements, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-safe-area-context@"3.1.9" from native-base@3.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!   native-base@"^3.3.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-safe-area-context@3.1.9
npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@"3.1.9" from native-base@3.3.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"^3.3.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\alexander\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alexander\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-05T23_04_00_233Z-debug-0.log
```

Even when I run `npm install react`, I still get similar error.

Please what do I do? I have equally deleted my android folder but it still doesn't work. I had a similar project that caused some errors like this but It wasn't this much and was quite easy to fix. I tried to copy the same dependency's version of that one to this one but it still failed.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-native-picker-select/@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@cometchat-pro/react-native-chat": "^3.0.10",
    "@eliav2/react-native-collapsible-view": "^1.4.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/inter": "^0.2.2",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4.2.2",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^5.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.1.1",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "@rodrigogs/mysql-events": "^0.6.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^7.14.2",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^4.6.1",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.7.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "emoji-mart-native": "^0.6.4-beta",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-application": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.4.6",
    "expo-av": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~0.8.6",
    "expo-device": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~10.1.3",
    "expo-file-system": "~13.1.4",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
    "expo-haptics": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-intent-launcher": "~10.1.3",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^11.0.3",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.14.1",
    "expo-permissions": "^13.1.1",
    "expo-server-sdk": "^3.6.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.7",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "firebase": "8.5",
    "flutterwave-node-v3": "^1.0.9",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "messagebird": "^3.7.2",
    "mixpanel-react-native": "^1.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "native-base": "^3.3.7",
    "navigation": "^5.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "onesignal-expo-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "paystack": "^2.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-animated-loader": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-autolink": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-easy-content-loader": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.1",
    "react-native-flash-message": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.1.20",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.7",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^4.3.11",
    "react-native-pager-view": "5.4.9",
    "react-native-paystack-webview": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-skeleton-content": "^1.0.24",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.15.0",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.12",
    "react-phone-input-2": "^2.14.0",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.44",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "sentry-expo": "^4.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.4.1",
    "stream-chat-expo": "^4.10.0",
    "twilio": "^3.75.0",
    "validate-nin": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.68.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: So no one has any solution?